# H2 select query fails in memory mode but not in embedded mode

Tags: h2

I'm using H2 1.3.173.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Flights (
  FlightId INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY HASH,
  AircraftId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DepartureDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  DepartureAirport VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  ArrivalDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ArrivalAirport VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
);
CREATE HASH INDEX idxFlightAircraftId ON Flights (AircraftId);
```

I'm looking for the first departure airport of each aircraft with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Flights A INNER JOIN (SELECT AircraftId, 
    MIN(DepartureDate) AS DepDate FROM Flights 
    GROUP BY AircraftId) B 
ON A.AircraftId = B.AircraftId 
AND A.DepartureDate = B.DepDate 
ORDER BY A.AircraftId ASC;
```

The query runs correctly in file mode, i.e. with the following URL:

```
jdbc:h2:file:~/db
```

but not in memory mode, i.e. with the following URL:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:db
```

In this case, I get the following exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: 
    "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"
```

Edit: exception message and error code:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM Flights A INNER JOIN (SELECT AircraftId, MIN(DepartureDate) AS DepDate FROM Flights GROUP BY AircraftId) B ON A.AircraftId = B.AircraftId AND A.DepartureDate = B.DepDate ORDER BY A.AircraftId ASC [50000-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:160) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:283) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:199) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:78) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:230) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:243) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.index.NonUniqueHashIndex.find(NonUniqueHashIndex.java:80) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.find(BaseIndex.java:126) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:155) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:328) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryGroupSorted(Select.java:164) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:618) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:314) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:284) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.index.ViewIndex.find(ViewIndex.java:253) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.find(BaseIndex.java:126) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:155) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:328) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:518) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:625) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:314) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:284) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:36) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:91) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:195) ~[h2-1.3.173.jar:1.3.173]
```

Any idea? Thanks. Laurent

Comment: Could you post the complete error message, including error code, as well as the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the H2 database. The same problem occurs with:

```
create table test(x int);
create hash index on test(x);
select 1 from test group by x;
```

This will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thank you. I've modified the HASH index as 'simple' index as temporary workaround.